# Use ncftpput to upload the folder content, not the folder itself

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp

I'm trying to upload the content of a folder to ftp server using `ncftpput -R -v -u "username" ftp.nixcraft.biz /nixcraft/forum /tmp/phpbb` but I don't want to create a `phpbb` folder I want to upload its content inside the `forum` folder.

How can I achieve this without changing the name of the folder from where I'm uploading?

Answer (score 4):

```
ncftpput -R -v -u "username" ftp.nixcraft.biz /nixcraft/forum /tmp/phpbb/*
```

Comment: Care to expand on why this will help?